# Can you interact with python from R Studio?

Tags: python, r, mixing

Is it possible to mix R with python. I've always have had curiosity for this languaje so it might be interesting to try it too.

Just trying to discover

Comment: See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/eng-python.html

Comment: Try looking at [How to Use R and Python Together? Try Using These 2 Packages](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/2022/03/how-to-use-r-and-python-together-try-these-2-packages/amp/).